# jquery dropdown rewrite from select to ul li

Tags: jquery

Dropdown menu (the right one, with city names like "gudauri") here dev.holiday.ge/xhtml/main.html must look like this: [image]

I tried with CSS but I think it is quite impossible...

My idea was to create another little jquery script that will modify contents of dropdown further dividing it into 3 's.

Current output:

```
<ul class="chzn-results">
<li class="group-result" id="control_1_chzn_g_0" style="display: list-item;">Mountain</li>
<li style="" class="active-result result-selected group-option" id="control_1_chzn_o_1">Gudauri</li>
<li style="" class="active-result group-option" id="control_1_chzn_o_2">Bakuriani</li>
<li style="" class="active-result group-option" id="control_1_chzn_o_3">Svaneti</li>

<li class="group-result" id="control_1_chzn_g_4" style="display: list-item;">Seaside</li>
<li style="" class="active-result group-option" id="control_1_chzn_o_5">Batumi</li>
<li style="" class="active-result group-option" id="control_1_chzn_o_6">Kobuleti</li>
<li style="" class="active-result group-option" id="control_1_chzn_o_7">Kvariati</li>

<li class="group-result" id="control_1_chzn_g_8" style="display: list-item;">Capital</li>
<li style="" class="active-result group-option" id="control_1_chzn_o_9">Tbilisi</li>
</ul>
```

Change into this:

```
<ul class="chzn-results" id="searchdropdown1">
<li class="group-result" id="control_1_chzn_g_0" style="display: list-item;">Mountain</li>
<li style="" class="active-result result-selected group-option" id="control_1_chzn_o_1">Gudauri</li>
<li style="" class="active-result group-option" id="control_1_chzn_o_2">Bakuriani</li>
<li style="" class="active-result group-option" id="control_1_chzn_o_3">Svaneti</li>
</ul>

<ul class="chzn-results" id="searchdropdown2">
<li class="group-result" id="control_1_chzn_g_4" style="display: list-item;">Seaside</li>
<li style="" class="active-result group-option" id="control_1_chzn_o_5">Batumi</li>
<li style="" class="active-result group-option" id="control_1_chzn_o_6">Kobuleti</li>
<li style="" class="active-result group-option" id="control_1_chzn_o_7">Kvariati</li>
</ul>

<ul class="chzn-results" id="searchdropdown3">
<li class="group-result" id="control_1_chzn_g_8" style="display: list-item;">Capital</li>
<li style="" class="active-result group-option" id="control_1_chzn_o_9">Tbilisi</li>
</ul>
```

What do you think?

Will this work at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It does work. I just tested the target UL html you mentioned above in Firebug and it worked. I added following attributes in the css class chzn-results{width:30%; float:left}. Do you need help in tansforming single UL into 3 UL's ?

```
$('#control_1_chzn .chzn-drop li.group-result').each(
function(index,val){
id='searchdropdown'+(1+index);
$('#control_1_chzn .chzn-drop').append('<ul class="chzn-results" style="width:30%; float:left;" id="'+id+'"></ul>');
$(this).nextUntil('li.group-result').appendTo($('#'+id));
$(this).prependTo($('#'+id));
}
);
$('#control_1_chzn .chzn-drop ul:first').remove();
```

Update: Added code to tranform the original UL list into 3 columns.

Comment: yes, that would be awesome since I have limited knowledge of jquery :P css part I can handle like Guru :D:D:D

Comment: really it worked? I tried with firebug, and cannot make it to work... I mean items aren't clickable anymore.

Comment: I did not check the clickability earlier. Let me check that and then try to create the jquery thing to transform

Comment: I think, not bieng able to click is caused since we changed the dom elements after registering the click event.

Comment: hm, so is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you tell me where the click event is registered for those li's ?

Comment: You mean which jquery part handles this? I used this plugin: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ have no idea where click event is registered :( thx for the code above btw! I will test it right away...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8869/discussion-between-kalyan-ganjam-and-sandrophoto)

Answer (score 0):

For the horizontal dividers to be implemented in css, you have to have an equal number of li's in all ul's, Or the dividers could be background graphics.

Comment: that's not an issue, float:left, with fixed height and it will work fine.